# Fun Project: Creating a simple OSRS Fishing calculator

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Before I describe the code, this is what it is based on.
[Old School Runescape Fishing XP Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRlzR.png)

The program is supposed to be able to ask the user how many types of fish they caught, tell the program which fish they caught, and ask how many of that particular fish that they caught. Once the program has all the inputs, it is supposed to
1. Calculate total XP earned from that particular fish.
2. Display the XP gained per fish per total amount caught.
3. Display a Bargraph showing the total amount of fish caught per fish.

I am working on making a side-by-side bar graph where it will display not only the total amount of fish caught for a particular fish but it's XP rates in relation to it.

The code is down below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

def fish_menu():
    print('Type out the name of the fish.')
    print('In the proper order once the prompt comes up.')
    print('1. Tuna')
    print('2. Lobster')
    print('3. Swordfish')
    print('4. Monkfish')
    print('5. Shark')

#Once the fish is determined, it will print out the XP totals.
def draw_bargraph():

    y_pos = np.arange(len(fishes2))
    #Create bar graph
    plt.bar(y_pos, caught2)
    #Names of axes
    plt.xticks(y_pos, fishes2)
    #Show graph
    plt.show()

def fish_calc():
    while len(fishes) > 0:
        if 'Tuna' in fishes:
            print('Catching {0} Tuna is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*80))
        elif 'Lobster' in fishes:
            print('Catching {0} Lobster is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*90)) 
        elif 'Swordfish' in fishes:
            print('Catching {0} Swordfish is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*100)) 
        elif 'Monkfish' in fishes:  
            print('Catching {0} Monkfish is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*120)) 
        elif 'Shark' in fishes:
            print('Catching {0} Shark is {1} total fishing XP'.format(caught[i], caught[i]*110)) 
        fishes.pop(0)
        caught.pop(0)       

def fish_calc2():
    if 'Tuna' in fishes:
        tunaxp = caught[a] * 100
        print('Catching {0} Tuna is {1} fishing XP.'.format(caught[a], tunaxp))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:    
        fish_menu()
        types_of_fish = int(input('How many kinds of fish did you catch?: '))
        fishes = []
        caught = []
        fishes2 = []
        caught2 = []
        if types_of_fish < 6:
            for i in range(1, types_of_fish+1): 
                which_fish = input('What was fish number {0}: '.format(i))
                catch = int(input('How many did you catch of {0}: '.format(which_fish)))
            #Adding the fish type and total amount into the empty lists
                fishes.append(which_fish)
                caught.append(catch)
                fishes2.append(which_fish)
                caught2.append(catch)
            #We are able to at least have the first fish entry be calculated
            #Order matters right now
            for i in range(types_of_fish):
                fish_calc()

        else:
            print('Input exceeds number of options.')
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input.')
    else:
        draw_bargraph()
```

**Some issues that I ran into were what if the user did not input the fish in the particular order that I made for them in the `fish_calc()` function.** I used the `while` loop to prevent continuous execution alongside the `fishes.pop(0)` function. For example,

```
###Fish menu that had to be created for it to work.###
###I want to remove the second line about "proper order"
Type out the name of the fish.
In the proper order once the prompt comes up.
1. Tuna
2. Lobster
3. Swordfish
4. Monkfish
5. Shark

###User input###
How many kinds of fish did you catch?: 2
What was fish number 1: Swordfish
How many did you catch of Swordfish: 10
What was fish number 2: Tuna
How many did you catch of Tuna: 3

###Output###
Catching 10 Tuna is 800 total fishing XP
Catching 3 Tuna is 240 total fishing XP
```

It recognized that 'Tuna' is in the list and performs the XP calc for 'Tuna' when it was actually meant for 'Swordfish'. However, the bar graph comes out correct.
[True BarGraph With False Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltN4G.png)

But if you input the fish in order, you will receive the correct results all the time.

```
Type out the name of the fish.
In the proper order once the prompt comes up.
1. Tuna
2. Lobster
3. Swordfish
4. Monkfish
5. Shark
How many kinds of fish did you catch?: 3
What was fish number 1: Lobster
How many did you catch of Lobster: 5
What was fish number 2: Swordfish
How many did you catch of Swordfish: 15
What was fish number 3: Shark
How many did you catch of Shark: 10

Catching 5 Lobster is 450 total fishing XP
Catching 15 Swordfish is 1500 total fishing XP
Catching 10 Shark is 1100 total fishing XP
```

The graph is also correct.
[True Graph with True Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6iq5.png)

Before, it wouldn't even be able to use the `fish_calc()` function if not for the `for i in range(types_of_fish):` in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section. Now, I just want to perfect the code to be more friendly to user input.

Comment: Each Stack Overflow question should be about one narrow, *specific* problem, with everything unrelated to that problem removed from both the question text and your code. See the [mre] definition in the Help Center, and [How Do I Ask And Answer Homework Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) on [meta] (not saying this is homework, but the advice -- to ask about your *problem*, not about your *assignment* -- is very applicable).

Comment: ...so, if the problem doesn't relate to printing a menu? No reason to include code to print a menu in the question. Problem doesn't relate to prompting for or capturing user input? Stop prompting for user input, and just hardcode specific variable values that are known to cause the issue; etc. Ideally, the question can be focused on the problem to the point that the search terms / title / etc. will be about the logic issue, not about the kind of program you encountered the issue while writing.

Comment: I appreciate the tips. I'm new to stackoverflow scene as well as coding scene but will do my best to limit the size of unnecessary information when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a Dictionary of the fish exp if that's just gonna be a constant value anyway. Pseudocoding:

```
fishMap = {"Tuna": 80, "Lobster": 90, ...}
```

then in `fish_calc()` you wouldn't have to create if/else statements, which are inherently ordered:

```
def fish_calc():
    for i in range(len(fishes)):
        # check if value is in the dictionary first
        fish = fishes[i]
        numFish = caught[i] 
        print('Catching {0} {1} is {2} total fishing XP'.format(numFish, fish, numFish*fishMap[fish]))
```

Of course, this isn't entirely case-insensitive either.

Comment: I see. A dictionary would be more sufficient. Thanks!